# Why would an EXCEPTION_FLT_OVERFLOW exception be thrown when a double is assigned or the value of assigned double would be changed?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, double

I meet two vary strange and weird dumps that are both about the double assignment.

**Background**

There is a QJsonValue(**Qt5.0**) just like this:

```cpp
/*!
    Assigns the value stored in \a other to this object.
 */
QJsonValue &QJsonValue::operator =(const QJsonValue &other)
{
    if (t == String && stringData && !stringData->ref.deref())
        free(stringData);

    t = other.t;
    dbl = other.dbl;

    if (d != other.d) {

        if (d && !d->ref.deref())
            delete d;
        d = other.d;
        if (d)
            d->ref.ref();

    }

    if (t == String && stringData)
        stringData->ref.ref();

    return *this;
}
```

And then, there are some operation just like this, it will call the method above.

```cpp
void test(QJsonObject obj, const QString& key)
{
    QJsonValue value = obj.value(key);
}
```

**Dump1**

Dump was happend at `dbl = other.dbl;`.

The exception infomation of this dump is:

> The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.

Why the operation that jsut copy the value from `other.dbl` to `this.dbl` will throw the exception?

[image]

**Dump2**

This is also associated with the operation `dbl = other.dbl`.

It was so weird that the value of `this.dbl` is not the same as the value of `other.dbl`.

[image]

**PS**

It's interesting that the `operator =` method of QJsonValue in **Qt5.12** has changed and I don't know why.

```cpp
/*!
    Assigns the value stored in \a other to this object.
 */
QJsonValue &QJsonValue::operator =(const QJsonValue &other)
{
    QJsonValue copy(other);
    swap(copy);
    return *this;
}

/*!
    \fn QJsonValue &QJsonValue::operator =(QJsonValue &&other)
    \since 5.10

    Move-assigns \a other to this value.
*/

/*!
    \fn void QJsonValue::swap(QJsonValue &other)
    \since 5.10

    Swaps the value \a other with this. This operation is very fast and never fails.
*/
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with VS, but are you sure you aren't assigning to a nullptr? In your first example, the address which gets assigned is `0x43EF` which is quite low. You could `assert(this != nullptr)` to verify this.

Comment: In the first example, `&dbl = 0x00cfceac {0.00000000000000000}` and `&dbl = 0x00cfcd4c {8.416762146484e-315#DEN}`. `this` won't be `nullptr` because the object is defined at stack. I don't know what the address `0x43EF` means and how it is generated.

Comment: If you look closely the write access violation in the second example happened during `stringData->ref.ref()`. See the yellow arrow in the left gutter. So the problem isn't specific to double assignment, it's just a memory problem.

Comment: Also did you look at the call stack to verify that you really are assigning an object on the stack and not somewhere else?

Comment: `stringData` and `dbl` are in a union. So the reason of invalid `stringData` is that the value of `dbl` is not the same as `other.dbl`. And I am really sure that the QJsonValue object is assigning on the stack, just like the operation I write at the question.